# WP_Query: How to get results from both meta_key options?

Tags: php, wp-query, sql

I have the following WP Query:

```
if(isset($_GET['scope']) && !empty($_GET['scope'])) {
    $scope = $_GET['scope'];
} else {
    $scope = '';
}

$foo = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'name',
            'value' => $scope,
            'compare' => '='
        ]
    ]
]);
```

And this dropdown menu:

```
<form class="criteria-form" action="<?=site_url('/page..')?>">
    <select name="scope" class="criteria-select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="" <?= $scope  ? 'selected' : '' ?>>All Foo</option>
        <option value="foo-red" <?= $scope == 'Foo Red' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Foo Red</option>
        <option value="Foo-green" <?= $scope == 'Foo Green' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Foo Green</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

All is working good for options `Foo Red` and `Foo green` because it returns specified values, but how can I select all values using the same compare operator? What I want to do is when user selects `All foo` he gets Red and Green. If I use `LIKE` operator instead of `=` I get Red and Green Foos mixed.

Maybe there is some better way to change operator for that specific select option and get all results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `meta_query` in a variable to achieve the desired result. Then you can fill the variable with your actual meta_query when your condition is met. Check out the code below.

```
$meta_query = array();

if ( isset($_GET['scope']) && !empty($_GET['scope']) ) {

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'name',
        'value'   => $_GET['scope'],
        'compare' => '='
    );

}

$foo = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        $meta_query
    )
]);
```

Comment: Thank you will try this right now

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.

Comment: @Maaverick, glad to hear! You're welcome :)